# Why is my code not working? - setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil

Tags: ios, database, swift, uitableview, firebase

Working on an app where I store data on Firebase and load the data into my TableView. Had to change the (old) code a little from a tutorial i found so I hope someone can spot the mistake i made. The user can add an event with a: name, date, description (all strings) and Image. This data is loaded into the TableView onto three "labels" and and image on top.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabaseUI

class EventViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //outlets for text & image
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDes: UITextView!

    //Database connection
    let rootref = FIRDatabase().reference()
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func submitEvent(sender: AnyObject) {

        let name = eventName.text
        let date = eventDate.text
        let text = eventDes.text
        var data: NSData = NSData()

        if let image = photoImageView.image {
            data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,0.1)!
        }

        let base64String = data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)

        let user: NSDictionary = ["name":name!, "date":date!, "text":text!, "photoBase64":base64String]

        //Add firebase child node
        let event = FIRDatabase().reference().child(name!)

        // Write data to Firebase
        event.setValue(user)

        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

    //UIImagePickerControllerDelegate methods

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        photoImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func addPicture(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
            imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:nil)
        }
    }
}
```

My TABLEVIEWCONTROLLER

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class EventTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventText: UITextView!

    let rootref = FIRDatabase().reference()
    var items = [NSDictionary]()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        items = [NSDictionary]()

        FIRDatabase.load()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //TableView Data
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        configureCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath)

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {

            let dict = items[indexPath.row]
            let name = dict["name"] as! String

            // delete data from firebase

            let event = FIRDatabase().reference().child(name)
            event.removeValue()
        }
    }

    // MARK:- Configure Cell

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let dict = items[indexPath.row]

        eventName.text = dict["name"] as? String
        eventDate.text = dict["name"] as? String
        eventText.text = dict["name"] as? String

        let base64String = dict["photoBase64"] as! String
        populateImage(cell, imageString: base64String)
    }

    func populateImage(cell:UITableViewCell, imageString: String) {

        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: imageString, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)

        let decodedImage = UIImage(data: decodedData!)

        cell.imageView!.image = decodedImage
    }

    //load data from Firebase
    func loadDataFromFirebase() {

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true


            rootref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                var tempItems = [NSDictionary]()


            for item in snapshot.children {
                let child = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                let dict = child.value as! NSDictionary
                tempItems.append(dict)
            }

            self.items = tempItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        })
    }
}
```

IMAGE TO GET AN IDEA OF MY WORK

[My app so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWXli.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
let user: NSDictionary = ["name":name!, "date":date!, "text":text!, "photoBase64":base64String]
```

You are doing a lot of forced unwrapping here. In fact, you do a lot of forced unwrapping in several places. When you do this you are saying "I am 100% sure there will ALWAYS be a value here". Avoid this a nearly all costs. That line should look like this.

```
if let unwrappedName = name , unwrappedDate = date, unwrappedText = text{
    let user: NSDictionary = ["name":unwrappedName, "date":unwrappedDate, "text":unwrappedText, "photoBase64":base64String]
}
```

Unwrapping optionals like this will keep your app from crashing. You should put a breakpoint here to see what value is nil. Every time you use a ! you should think VERY carefully about about it.

Comment: THIS. People nowadays write code as if the `!` will magically create valid values when needed!

Comment: Beginning Swift programmers should pretend the force-unwrap operator does not exist. In D&D terminology, you should have to earn a certain amount of experience points before that weapon is unlocked for you. :)

Comment: So best advice here is to remove ALL of my force-unwrapping? But it keeps giving me an error if I remove the "!"... sorry for being a noob here guys its been like a week already trying to connect this app to firebase :(
Will be home in a few hours to test again ill keep you updated..

Comment: The error you posted says there is a nil in a place where there shouldn't be a nil. Specifically when running the method setObjectForKey, a method on the NSDictionary class. Its likely that a specific value you are setting in this dictionary is nil and crashing your app. Proper unwrapping of optionals would prevent this crash.

Comment: @Andrew McKinley - Thanks for the explanation i need to read more on this! However, after changing the NSdictionary i got an error on --> event.setValue(user) <-- it states "cannot convert value of type (user).Type to expected argument type 'AnyObject' " Why is this happening? What value is expected here?

Comment: I've never used FIRDatabase before so I can't help you here. I suggest looking at the specific class type you need and try to convert it (say event.setValue(user as? Dictionary). Mark my answer correct if I helped and post another question specific to FIRDatabase if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for your help the code worked out and I am working on new issues as we speak haha but thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is where you set up your database connection.

You have: `let rootref = FIRDatabase().reference()`

It should be:`let rootref = FIRDatabase().database().reference()`

I was getting the same error and this fixed it for me.