# Firebase Storage error: setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In my Image Picker's `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, I want to connect to my Firebase Storage to upload the selected image. The first line of code (which creates a reference to the storage) already throws an error. This is the reference:

```
let storageReference:FIRStorageReference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://myapp-5xxxx.appspot.com").child("profilepic.png")
```

The error is as follows:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: *** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil
```

I don't understand who's calling the `setObjectForKey` method or to which object this method belongs, so I have absolutely no idea where to look for this issue.

All I know is that the line of code mentioned above is the one causing this error. I'm very new to Firebase, so I apologize if this is just another noob mistake. I still hope someone can help me out though.

By the way, yes, I did call the `FIRAPP.configure()` method in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of the `AppDelegate` and yes, I did include the `GoogleServices-info.plist` file into my project. I hope this prevents some unnecessary questions from being asked.

**Update:**

Method in which the storage reference is created:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    // Get reference to storage folder and upload selected image into it
    let storageReference:FIRStorageReference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://myapp-5xxxx.appspot.com").child("profilepic.png")
    let selectedImage:UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let imageUrl:String? // This will be the download URL that gets returned from the FIRStorageUploadTask after completion

    // Method to store image URL in MySQL database
    self.storeImageUrlInDatabase(with: imageUrl)

}
```

And a screenshot of the app crash after the exception breakpoint gets hit:

[image: Screenshot of the app crash after exception breakpoint gets hit]

**Update 2:**

A screenshot of the call stack after the app crashes...
[image: Screenshot of the call stack]

Comment: Is it possible the error is actually on a different line?  Something like `storageReference.setValue(myDictionary)`.  Can you post a bit more of your code surrounding the line your reference?

Comment: @Bek This is the only line of code related to the `storageReference` object. I don't have a `setValue()` method called on this object. Am I supposed to do that first?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Firebase.  I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063268/why-is-my-code-not-working-setobjectforkey-key-cannot-be-nil which is what led me to ask about a `setValue()` line.  Without seeing a bit more code, I can't think of anything else, sorry.  Do you have breakpoints on exception set?  And it's definitely on that line?

Comment: Can you print a more complete stack trace leading up to the error? I can't think of a place off the top of my head where this would be invoked based on the operation you're doing in that code snippet, and I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald It really isn't that complicated. I called `FIRAPP.configure()` in the `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method and immediately after that I call the `storageReference` line (mentioned in my question above) in my `ViewController`, in the Image Picker's `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method. There is literally NOTHING else Firebase-related in my entire project, so posting any other code than what I've already mentioned would be completely irrelevant to finding an answer to my question.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald And the reason I know 100% sure that this is the line of code that causes the error, is because I created an exception breakpoint which points out this line when crashing and if I comment out that line of code, the project works perfectly fine without any errors or crashes. My best guess is that I missed something in the setup-process of Firebase. I imported all the required files, downloaded the `GoogleServices-Info.plist` file from my project in the Firebase-console and then started typing this first line of code. Did I miss anything crucial here?

Comment: @FreddyBenson I'm going to reflect your question back: "I don't understand who's calling the `setObjectForKey` method or to which object this method belongs, so I have absolutely no idea where to look for this issue." I can't repro this, so unless you give more info in the form of a screenshot of the exception breakpoint, including the call stack, or a pasted copy of said call stack, there's nothing I (nor anyone else) can do for you. I don't even know what version of XCode or iOS you're running this on, which could make a difference.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Updated my original post with some more code and a screenshot, like you asked. So to re-phrase the question: What object is calling the `setObjectForKey` method which causes the crash (bottom line in the Debugger)? Oh by the way, if it's of any help to you: I'm running Xcode 8.0, iOS 10.0 (Swift 3).

Comment: Can you post an image of the call stack as well? The log "Creating an image format with unknown type is an error" is the only suspicious thing here, and I have a very hard time believing that the reference generation code is crashing.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Hey, sorry it took so long. I had some problems with my Macbook freezing very frequently yesterday, but I finally managed to get the screenshot of the call stack. You can find it in the original post. I do notice there a few other FIRStorage methods being called, but I can't access them. For some reason I can't find them when I'm trying to call them either (expected Xcode to autocomplete the methods after I'd type in "FIRStorage.", but I got nothing). I hope you can make anything out of it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, this is the call that I thought was failing. There's only one way this call could fail: if the name of your `FIRApp` is `nil` (I make a call like `dict[app.name] = value`). TBH I'm not sure how this could happen unless you're creating a custom `FIRApp` (which it doesn't look like), or your `FIRApp.configure()` call isn't succeeding.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Yeah, I think it's the latter: my `configure()` method sometimes doesn't even get called. The Debugger sometimes logs an error which says "You haven't configured the default app yet", which doesn't make any sense, because if I actually get rid of the `FIRApp.configure()` method by commenting that line out, the app doesn't even get built and it throws like a 110 build errors at me. So calling the `configure()` avoids build time errors, but doesn't take care of runtime errors. I'll try to contact someone from Firebase to see if they can figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @MikeMcDonald I think I just figured out the source of my problem and you were right: `FIRApp.configure()` doesn't get called. It doesn't have anything to do with the `FIRApp` object though: the problem is that my `AppDelegate`'s `didFinishLauchingWithOptions` method (in which I'm calling the `configure()` method) doesn't get called. I've had this problem for a while now and I also caused me a lot of issues with loading `UserDefaults` data, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888601/private-func-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-not-being-called-swift-3/39890160#39890160