# Can't Logout in Twitter SDK using swift 4.2 version

Tags: ios, swift, twitter

While fetching sessionStore from Twitter SDK, it's getting crash!
**TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore**
See the attached image for the issue.[image]

I'm getting this issue in swift 4.2, before it was working fine.

Comment: I found the root cause, the problem is not as I post here, the problem is like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888601/private-func-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-not-being-called-swift-3), so in app-delegate class application - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you need to call a method that starts up the twitter session before you can call any other methods from the twitter sdk. According to twitter's [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki/Installation#initialize-twitter-kit), you should add the following to your AppDelegate:

> Paste your own key and secret below
>
> ````swift
> func application(_ application: UIApplication,
> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
> [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
>     TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey:"hTpkPVU4pThkM0",
> consumerSecret:"ovEqziMzLpUOF163Qg2mj")
>     return true }
>
> func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options:
> [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
>     return TWTRTwitter.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) } ```
> ````

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is I'm already doing in the code. Is there any other way to check the sessionStore, whether we have some value or not?

Comment: The crash you are getting says that the `start` method has not yet been called. You should look back at your `AppDelegate` to make sure that it is being called correctly. As a debugging step, you could even paste that code directly before you are calling `.sessionStore` to make sure that your assumptions are correct.

Comment: I found the root cause, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is not called, while updating the swift version this function was mark as private, so that the issue, thanks for your comment. I have the similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888601/private-func-didfinishlaunchingwithoptions-not-being-called-swift-3